# Submitting form in Bootstrap modal will not open second modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have created a form in a Bootstrap modal and my goal is to submit the form in that modal and have that modal close and then have a second modal appear with a confirmation message.

Currently, the form is submitting and the data is being posted to the correct table in the database and the modal with the form in it is closing, but the second modal is not appearing after the first modal closes and I cannot figure out why.

I am using Python Flask and Jinja2 and Bootstrap version 4.3.1 and an SQLite database.

Here is my code for the modal with the form in it:

```
{% for section in sections %}
  <div class="modal fade" id="classInfoModal{{ section.crn }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
   hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div id="class-sections-modal-content" class="modal-content">
          <form action="#" method="POST" role="form" id="addCourseForm">
            <div id="class-sections-modal-body" class="modal-body">
              <p id="class-sections-modal-text">
                Course: {{ section.course_id }}<br>
                Title: {{ section.course_title }}<br>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_crn" value= "{{ section.crn }}" />
                CRN: {{ section.crn }}<br>
                Sect: {{ section.section_num }}<br>
                Instructor: {{ section.professor_name }}<br>
                <input type="hidden" name="course_semester" value= "{{ section.semester }}" />
                Semester: {{ section.semester }}<br>
                Days: {{ section.day }}<br>
                Time: {{ section.start_time }} - {{ section.end_time }}<br>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div id="class-sections-modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
              <input type="submit" id="class-info-modal-button-add" class="btn class-sections-modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#classAddedModal" value="ADD">
              <button type="button" id="class-info-modal-button-cancel" class="btn class-sections-modal-button" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <!--modal end-->
{% endfor %}
```

Here is my code for the second modal:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="classAddedModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div id="class-sections-modal-content" class="modal-content">
        <div id="class-sections-modal-body" class="modal-body">
          <p id="class-sections-modal-text">
          Course successfully added!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="class-sections-modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" id="class-added-modal-button-close" class="btn class-sections-modal-button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The classAddedModal is supposed to appear after the user clicks the 'submit' button in the first modal window. I have also tried changing the submit button from an input field to a button and that didn't work either.

Does anyone know why the classAddedModal isn't opening?

Thank you.

Comment: How will you submit the form? With ajax or the normal way?

Comment: @ΑntonisPapadakis I am not using ajax, so I am submitting it using POST